# Infinispan cluster error: Class for magic number cannot be found

Tags: infinispan

I have 2 spring boot applications each connected to it's own Infinispan server in a cluster on 2 virtual machines.

After starting the applications, every few seconds I get this exceptions in app log:

```
o.j.p.MPING: JGRP000191: failed receiving packet from /10.254.1.36:21246: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class for magic number 23294 cannot be found

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class for magic number 23294 cannot be found
        at org.jgroups.conf.ClassConfigurator.create(ClassConfigurator.java:118) ~[jgroups-4.2.9.Final.jar!/:4.2.9.Final]
        at org.jgroups.Message.readHeader(Message.java:836) ~[jgroups-4.2.9.Final.jar!/:4.2.9.Final]
        at org.jgroups.Message.readFrom(Message.java:709) ~[jgroups-4.2.9.Final.jar!/:4.2.9.Final]
        at org.jgroups.protocols.MPING.run(MPING.java:198) [jgroups-4.2.9.Final.jar!/:4.2.9.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

and

```
o.j.p.MPING: JGRP000191: failed receiving packet from /10.254.1.28:63093: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -27011 out of bounds for length 100

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -27011 out of bounds for length 100
        at org.jgroups.conf.ClassConfigurator.create(ClassConfigurator.java:129) ~[jgroups-4.2.9.Final.jar!/:4.2.9.Final]
        at org.jgroups.Message.readHeader(Message.java:836) ~[jgroups-4.2.9.Final.jar!/:4.2.9.Final]
        at org.jgroups.Message.readFrom(Message.java:709) ~[jgroups-4.2.9.Final.jar!/:4.2.9.Final]
        at org.jgroups.protocols.MPING.run(MPING.java:198) [jgroups-4.2.9.Final.jar!/:4.2.9.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

Everything is up and running, functioning good, but the app log gets too big and unreadable in a while, causing more resource consumption. I see it's related to jGroups but why it appears and how to solve those exceptions, anybody had the same issue?

Thank you for your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

As it is jgroups MPING discovery protocol I would guess that there are other instances with the same MPING multicast address.
Because of this there might be other instances with different JGroups versions sending responses or requests to your cluster.

I would recommend to use not the defaults for MPING addresses.
Other option is to change the configuration to TCPPING where you need to add all the cluster members by IP:port